# Datetime conversion to make a time series plot with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, datetime-format, area-chart

I'm trying to create an area chart with a pandas DataFrame.

Here's what I get when I plotted the data as it was imported.

```
debt[['Record_Date', 'Debt_Held_by_the_Public']].plot(kind='area')
```

[image: First Plot]

I converted the "Record_Date" field to a datetime field, and I get nothing when trying to plot it.

```
debt['Record_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(debt['Record_Date'])
debt[['Record_Date', 'Debt_Held_by_the_Public']].plot(kind='area')
```

[image: Second Plot]

What am I doing wrong? The Record_Date was listed as an object originally. Once I converted that field, it shows up as datetime64.

This message appears when trying to make the second plot.

> TypeError: The DTypes <class 'numpy.dtype[uint8]'> and <class 'numpy.dtype[datetime64]'> do not have a common DType. For example they cannot be stored in a single array unless the dtype is `object`.

Comment: Could you add some sample data to your question? Can you try if `debt[['Record_Date', 'Debt_Held_by_the_Public']].plot(x='Record_Date', y='Debt_Held_by_the_Public', kind='area')` works?

Comment: Thank you Timus. That worked. Much appreciated.